# How can I make applescript write the value stored in a variable wherever the insertion point happens to be?

Tags: applescript

How can I make applescript write the value stored in a variable wherever the insertion point happens to be, no matter what file or application happens to be in focus?

Answer (score 0):

You must simulate keyboard entries via Keystroke command. But it means you must convert your variable in string first. The second issue you will have is that your application must be activate, and your script running (I guess in background), should not become upfront. Something like  bellow (in this case, Application = TextEdit)

```
set myVariable to 10
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
delay 1 
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (myVariable as string)
end tell
```

Comment: Using System Events/GUI Scripting to emulate user input is hacky and unreliable though. Depending on what s/he's doing, the OP might be better packaging the script as a Service. They're easy to create in Automator (which includes Actions for running scripts), you can give them keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences or run them from the app's own Services submenu, and they rely on actual system APIs, not a wing and a prayer, so will be much more robust.

Comment: @pbell This works up to a point (shame I'm not allowed to express gratitude), i.e., it allows the applescript to write the value of the variable, but so far it's still tied to only one application.

Comment: Now I've found that, if you use 'frontmost application' instead of a named application, it still works, now  (apparently) anywhere. I've tested it in iText, Excel and a web form in Firefox.

Here is part of the script:

`tell application "System Events"
set x to {random number from 1 to 250}
delay 0.5
tell frontmost application
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (x as string)
end tell
delay 0.2
key code 48
key code 36
end tell`

By the way, I never knew until today there could be more 'tell's than 'end tell's in a script.

@foo Not tried the automator method yet.

Comment: pbell, I've now found that, if you use 'frontmost application' instead of a named application, it still works, now  (apparently) anywhere. I've tested it in iText, Excel and a web form in Firefox.

Here is part of the script:

`tell application "System Events"
set x to {random number from 1 to 250}
delay 0.5
tell frontmost application
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (x as string)
end tell
delay 0.2
key code 48
key code 36
end tell`

By the way, I never knew until today there could be more 'tell's than 'end tell's in a script.

@foo Not tried the automator method yet.

Comment: Sorry about bad formatting etc., but I'm totally baffled by Stackoverflow's system.